Lighweight Linux Distro for tablet pc
I have an old Windows Tablet (Lenovo MIIX 320) with:

4 GB RAM LPDDR3 (1600MHz)
64 GB ROM
integrated Intel® HD Graphics
Intel Atom Processor quad core Z8350 (1,44GHz L2 2MB) Burst Frequency 1,92GHz processor


Windows 10 is freezing so much, that you can't watch even YouTube videos anymore. I tried some Linux Distros, but Ubuntu and PopOS! were pretty much the same. I also tried Plasma Mobile and JingOS, it was a little bit better, but the apps were crashing. I just want a distro with a lightweight desktop environment and some support for touch screens.
I had a good run with Chrome OS Flex, it was smooth, I could watch YouTube videos, but sound wasn't working.
I tried FydeOS, but there was the same problem with sound and it was also lagging.
Does anyone knows a Linux distro (or other OS), that will work smooth for YouTube watching and some browsing?

Why ask here if you don't plan to use Ubuntu?

Try Raspberry Pi OS for Desktop. https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Also, have you tried Kubuntu after removing snap? KDE (in Kubuntu) has good support for touch, but is not as heavy as gnome

Please note that this site is about Ubuntu. Recommendations for generic distro are off topic here, and this question will be eventually closed by the moderators.

In case you use RPi OS, I made a touch screen rotator app (which also configures two-finger-right-click guesture) for it, which can be tweaked a little bit so that it works on your hardware https://github.com/archisman-panigrahi/surface-RT-screen-rotator

Sorry for the misunderstanding. I would love to have Ubuntu on in, I like the tablet-friendlines in Gnome with the big button, gestures, etc. I just want it to run a little faster.
I thought maby a other Ubuntu flavor, like Linux Lite, something more XFCE, or maby KDE again. I had Kubuntu on it for a little while, but the YouTube was freezing (even on alternative web browsers), so I moved on.
And I would be really happy, if there where a script, where I can make it more efficient, faster, ...
